# Cambiar idioma de Google maps en Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Uso el objeto Google-maps para mostrar mapas, mis apps tiene la opción de cambiar el idioma de la app, lo que no encuentro es como hacer que la vista google-maps los nombres de las ciudades etc.. aparezcan en el idioma especificado.

Por lo visto obtiene por defecto el idioma establecido en el teléfono.
¿Cómo se puede definir el Locale del mapa de google?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el idioma usando el objeto [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

Por ejemplo si usas un Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String idioma = "es_ES";
    Locale locale = new Locale(idioma);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
}
```

Comment: lo vi en una pregunta en la stackoverflow en ingles, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android, no lo he probado personalmente.

Comment: Ya ví la respuesta que comentas en el sitio en inglés gracias, de hecho agregué la mía ahí para validar métodos obsoletos.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas un `Fragment` puedes definir el `locale` en el método donde inicializas el mapa:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String language= "ru"; //idioma Ruso.
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
           config.setLocale(locale);
           getContext().createConfigurationContext(config);
        }else { //Obsoleto
           config.locale = locale;
           getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

...
...
```

...

Es importante notar que las descripciones en el mapa no soporta todos los lenguajes, este es un ejemplo en idioma Ruso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los códigos los puedes obtener de :
https://www.transifex.com/explore/languages/